# How do I hide a jqGrid column of variable name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, hide

I have a jqGrid column which name may change (is a variable), how do I get the name and hide it?

Something along the lines of the below (which don't work)

```
 $('#tblGridName').jqGrid('hideCol',4);
```

or

```
var infoName = $('.ui-jqgrid-htable th:eq(4)').text();
$('#tblGridName').jqGrid('hideCol',infoName );
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use

```
var cm = myGrid.getGridParam("colModel");
```

to get the current `colModel`. Then `cm[4].name` is the name of the column. So

```
var colPos = 4;
var myGrid = $('#tblGridName');
myGrid.jqGrid('hideCol', myGrid.getGridParam("colModel")[colPos].name);
```

do what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, found the answer almost right off.

Just amended this

```
var infoName = $('.ui-jqgrid-htable th:eq(4)').text();
$('#tblGridName').jqGrid('hideCol',infoName );
```

to be

```
var infoName = $.trim( $('.ui-jqgrid-htable th:eq(4)').text() );
$('#tblGridName').jqGrid('hideCol',infoName );
```

Any better solutions welcomed.

Comment: Be aware that `.trim()` is not supported in all browsers. You should probably use jQuery's `$.trim()` method. `var infoName = $.trim( $('.ui-jqgrid-htable th:eq(4)').text() );`